# how to import public static field from class in android data binding

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

I want to import some string from interface constant in android layout data binding.

Gradle build fails if i use this line

```
android:drawableRight="@{item.icon.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.FOOD_TYPE_NON_VEG)? @drawable/ic_nonveg : @drawable/ic_veg}"
```

But below line works

```
android:drawableRight="@{item.icon.equalsIgnoreCase(`nonveg`)? @drawable/ic_nonveg : @drawable/ic_veg}"
```

Sample xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="Constants"
            type="com.amelio.utils.Constants"/>

    </data>

    <TextView
        style="@style/tvVerySmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:drawableRight="@{item.icon.equalsIgnoreCase(`nonveg`)? @drawable/ic_nonveg : @drawable/ic_veg}"
        />

</layout>
```

and Constants interface is

```
public interface Constants {
    String FOOD_TYPE_NON_VEG  = "nonveg";
}
```

**How to import string from interface in xml layout in databinding?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `import`, not `variable`:

```
<data>
    <import type="yourfullpackagepath.Constants"/>
</data>
```

Comment: And how to use it?

Answer (score 5):

Import the class where your `public` or `internal` constant is present:

```
<data>
    <import type="com.ananth.nasaphotooftheday.utility.Constant"/>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.ananth.nasaphotooftheday.ui.main.MainViewModel" />
</data>
```

Use it according to your use, for example:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_fullscreen"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@{(viewModel.media.type == Constant.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) ? @drawable/ic_play : @drawable/ic_fullscreen}"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_large" />
```